# Javascript/HTML5 pong game only working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, pong

I currently finished a Pong game as a college assignment, but it's only working in Google Chrome. I've searched for a few hours on Google, but can't seem to find the problem.

It's not working in the newest Firefox, and also not workign in IE9.

This is the code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas;
            var ctx;  

            var score1 = 0;
            var score2 = 0;

            // beginpositie plankjes
            var x = 200;
            var y = 380;
            var x2 = 200;
            var y2 = 10;

            // beginpositie en grootte van het balletje
            var x3 = 100;
            var y3 = 200;
            var size = 5;

            // snelheid balletje
            var sx = 0;
            var sy = 0;

            // snelheid plankjes
            var dx = 7;
            var dy = 7;

            // canvas afmeting
            var BREEDTE = 500;
            var HOOGTE = 400;

            function hervatSpel(){
                if(sx == 0 && sy == 0){
                    x3 = 100;
                    y3 = 200;
                    sx = 2;
                    sy = 2;
                }
            }

            function stopSpel(){
                if(sx != 0 || sy != 0){
                    x3 = 100;
                    y3 = 200;
                    sx = 0;
                    sy = 0;
                }
            }

            function resetScore(){
                score1 = 0;
                score2 = 0;
            }

            function rect(x,y,w,h){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }            

            function circ(){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
                ctx.arc(x3,y3,size,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();

                // collision detection zijkanten
                if(x3<(size/2) || x3>(BREEDTE-size)){
                    sx = -sx;
                }

                // collision detection plankjes  
                if(y3 > (HOOGTE-20) && x3 > x && x3 < (x+100)){
                    sy = -sy;
                }

                if(y3 < 20 && x3 > x2 && x3 < (x2+100)){
                    sy =-sy;
                }

                // collision detection onder- en bovenkant
                if(y3<size){
                    // onderste speler scoort
                    // reset balletje
                    x3 = 100;
                    y3 = 200;
                    sx = 0;
                    sy = 0;
                    // reset plankjes
                    x = 200;
                    y = 380;
                    x2 = 200;
                    y2 = 10;
                    // update score
                    score2 += 1;
                }  
                if(y3>(HOOGTE-size)){
                    // bovenste speler scoort
                    x3 = 100;
                    y3 = 200;
                    sx = 0;
                    sy = 0;

                    x = 200;
                    y = 380;
                    x2 = 200;
                    y2 = 10;

                    score1 += 1;
                }

                x3+=sx;
                y3+=sy;
            }

            function clear(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,BREEDTE,HOOGTE);
            }

            function init(){
                canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                return setInterval(draw, 10);
            }

            function draw(){
                clear();
                ctx.fillStyle = "9CC8F7";
                rect(0,0,BREEDTE,HOOGTE);
                ctx.fillStyle = "1A6CC4";
                rect(x,y,100,10);
                rect(x2,y2,100,10);
                circ();
                ctx.font="18px Trebuchet MS";
                ctx.fillText('Speler 1:',10,30);
                ctx.fillText('Speler 2:',10,380);
                ctx.fillText(score1,100,30);
                ctx.fillText(score2,100,380);
            }

            function doKeyDown(evt){
                switch (evt.keyCode) {
                    case 37:  /* linker pijltje wordt ingedrukt */
                    if (x > 0){
                        x -= dx;
                    }
                    break;
                    case 39:  /* rechter pijltje wordt ingedrukt */
                    if (x + 100 < BREEDTE){
                        x += dx;
                    }
                    break;
                    case 87: /* w-toets wordt ingedrukt */
                    if (x2 > 0){
                        x2 -= dx;
                    }
                    break;
                    case 83: /*s-toets wordt ingedrukt */
                    if (x2 + 100 < BREEDTE){
                        x2 += dx;
                    }
                    break;
                    case 13: /* ENTER wordt ingedrukt */
                    if(sx == 0 || sy == 0){
                    sx = 2;
                    sy = 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            init()
            window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
        </script>
```

Some of it is in Dutch, but I don't think this is relevant anyway.

Comment: We're not just going to debug your PasteBin code for you. Show some effort! What have you tried? Are there any errors in the console? Could you describe what "not working" means, exactly? And please post the relevant code here, not on an external site. Thank you.

Comment: Hello minitech. I don't get any errors in my IDE (Netbeans) at all. I tried using loading the javascript with the <body onload=""> function and also with window.onload in the script itself. For some unknown reason it just doesn't load the canvas in IE and Firefox.

Comment: and the firebug and debug on firefox/ie any console errors?

Comment: Also, the code itself is working without any errors in Chrome. So it's not the code itself. I'm really clueless here, because for some reason it just not appears in other browsers.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using IE developer tools? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Ramon: Is IE in compatibility mode? Check the F12 developer tools. I don't know what level of integration Netbeans has with browsers, but just make sure in Firefox with Ctrl+Shift+K.

Comment: Going to try that now Carlos, thanks.

Comment: Ok I've tried debugging in IE9, and it gives the following error:
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'. 

The error is on the line with: ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your colors need to have a beginning `#`:

```
               ctx.fillStyle = "9CC8F7";
               rect(0,0,BREEDTE,HOOGTE);
               ctx.fillStyle = "1A6CC4";
```

Should be:

```
               ctx.fillStyle = "#9CC8F7";
               rect(0,0,BREEDTE,HOOGTE);
               ctx.fillStyle = "#1A6CC4";
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ufepux/2/edit)**

Comment: Thanks alot, this makes it working in Firefox now! Still not working in IE, though.

Comment: That's odd, it was working for me in IE9. Can you tell me any more about what's not working specifically? Make sure your document and browser modes are both set to IE9 in the settings (F12).

Comment: Everything is working in both Chrome and Mozilla. When I try to load it in IE9, it just gives a blank page. But I've found a solution on Google, I've changed Document Mode to IE9 standards (it was on IE7 standards).

Comment: Yeah, That's what I was trying to explain in the comment above. Glad it's working for you now.